# SSIS Packages Deployment to SQL Server getting Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I try to deploy my package to SQL Server and already have the catalog in SQL Server.
My package only contain Procedure and Import Excel process.

But I am getting this error and could not find any solution.

I try to search about this exception but no luck

```
Unrecognized configuration section system.web/system.web.
(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 243)
```

Here is the full error messages

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception. 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.web/system.web.
(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 243)
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.Co
    ...
System.TypeInitializationException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.GetOperationInfo(SqlInt64 operation_id, OperationType type, ServerOperationStatus status, Int64& object_id)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.checkParameters(SqlInt64 object_id, SqlInt64 operation_id, OperationType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Serve... (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.7001&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=6522&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: database
Error Number: 6522
Severity: 16
State: 1
Procedure: deploy_project_internal


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel.SqlHelper.ExecuteSQLCommand(SqlStoreConnection storeConnection, CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, SqlParameter[] parameters, ExecuteType execType, Int32 commandTimeout)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder.DeployProject(String projectName, Byte[] projectStream)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeployExportProjectHelper.DeployProject(CatalogFolder folder, Project project)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.Deploy(CatalogFolder folder, Project project)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.DeployProject()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Deployment.DeployProjectPage.DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

[image]

Here is my SSIS Version and SQL Server version
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the `system.web` structure

```
 <system.web>
        <processModel autoConfig="true"/>

        <httpHandlers/>

        <membership>
            <providers>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager>
            <providers>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
```

Please if there are some answer for this

Thanks

Comment: So have you edited the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` file? It sounds like someone/something has nested another set of `system.web` elements inside the existing `system.web` element.

Comment: I have not edit the file

Comment: Can you check the file? There error is pretty specific - and can be replicated by inserting `<system.web></system.web>` inside a working file's `system.web` element structure.

Comment: Hi I already edit the post and show the system.web element. I dont really understand about the code since I am new on this thing

Comment: Backup and Try replacing the file `machine.config` from another machine which have same version if you have one